# Efficient LINQ to Entities query case?

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I have this case where I need some help on refactoring a good query to fetch data from the SQL Server database.

The case is say you have a database with 20000 songs and each song has 6 fields with each field is a category (e.g. Category1 = Dance, Category2 = House, Category3 = Deep, Category4 = Minimal, Category5 = null, Category6 = null).

How would you approach when you want to get all the songs that is in Dance and House but doesn't matter all other categories? or Deep and Minimal and doesn't matter all other?

I can say which categories are asked!

I can imagine an approach where has lots of combinations....and it feels really ugly...

Comment: It feels like you could benefit from a normalization here. Can you modify the data structure? And where can I listen to the music? :)

Comment: Hehe i can't benefit from normalization because this is what they're asking (believe me I wish I could do that)...the music is on the clients (cafe-bar, clubs, hotels) playing automatic lists created by the master company, but I guess you can find all over the net what you need :) Any other thoughts? :P

Answer (score 0):

My exemple:

```
(from song in SongRepository
where song.Cateroy1 == Dance || song.Cateroy2 == Dance || song.Cateroy3 == Dance || song.Cateroy4 == Dance || song.Cateroy5 == Dance
select song)
.Union(from song in SongRepository
where song.Cateroy1 == House || song.Cateroy2 == House || song.Cateroy3 == House || song.Cateroy4 == House || song.Cateroy5 == House
select song)
```

This solution is bad.
My opinion, your shema of database is bad, . Look how to join and association table

```
table Song
SongID
SongTitle
SongCategoryID

table Category
CategoryID
CategoryTitle

table SongCategory
SongCategoryID
SongID
CategoryID
```

and your linq request :

```
SongRepository.Where(song => song.SongCategory.Category.CategoryTitle = "Dance" 
|| song.SongCategory.Category.CategoryTitle = "House").Select(song =>song);
```

or dynamic request

```
  var query = SongRepository.Where(song => song.SongCategory.Category.CategoryTitle = "Dance").Select(song =>song); 

 query = query.Union(SongRepository.Where(song => song.SongCategory.Category.CategoryTitle = "House").Select(song =>song));
```

I dont know if the code run ... ^^

Good luck !

Comment: Thanx for the answer, I will examine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use query like this in plain SQL to accomplish your task:

```
SELECT * FROM Songs
WHERE 'Dance' IN (Category1,Category2,Category3,Category4,Category5,Category6)
AND 'House'   IN (Category1,Category2,Category3,Category4,Category5,Category6)
```

but as far as I remember Linq-to-entities doesn't support `IN` so you'll need something else.

---

Another half-hacky approach which should work on EF 4.0 (here I'm assuming that `#` is a symbol which will be never present in your category names)

```
var result = Songs
   .Select(s => new {Name = s.Name, SearchString = '#'+s.Category1+'#'+s.Category2+'#'+...+'#'})
   .Where(p => p.SearchString.Contains("#Dance#") && p.SearchString.Contains("#House#"))
   .Select(p => p.Name);
```

---

And last solution - normalize your database.